# Using fork() and execl() is creating 2 sub-processes

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork, exec

I am trying to fork() a process and make it execute a ffmpeg screen recording (which is stopped using a SIGINT).
I have written a popen2() function that forks() and then calls execl() like below. But using this I am not able to kill the fork'ed process as I see 2 sub-process in ps.

```
4508   744 pts/0    S+   12:53   0:00 sh -c ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0 abcd.mp4      
1883  696608 pts/0  Rl+  12:53   0:52 ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0 abcd.mp4
```

This is the popen2() function I am using which returns the PID of the fork'ed process

```
pid_t popen2()
{
  const pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    execl("ffmpeg", "-video_size 1024x768 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i : 0.0", NULL);
    exit(1);
  }
  // parent process.
  return pid;
}
```

I kill it in the parent process when my session is over.

```
const auto wait_result = waitpid(screen_recorder_pid_, &status, WNOHANG);
// child is still running, kill.
if (wait_result == 0)
{
  const auto kill_result = kill(screen_recorder_pid_, SIGINT);
}
```

My question is

1. Why are 2 sub-process being created? I thought using execl should replace the current program
2. How do I kill the process from the parent?

Comment: is `ffmpeg` a shell script or does it lack the executable permission?

Comment: What if you try: `execl("ffmpeg", "ffmpeg", "-video_size", "1024x768", "-framerate", "20", "-f", "x11grab", "-i", ":", "0.0", NULL);`? (and should the `:` really be separated from the `0.0` and the `-` from `i`?)

Comment: @Alan `ffmpeg` is a binary executable, not a shell script.

Comment: _@kode18_  _"How do I kill the process from the parent?"_ Use `SIGKILL` instead of `SIGINT`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ normally yes, nothing stopping you from creating a shell script called `ffmpeg` which then invokes the executable though

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah, OK. I missed the `ps` output. It looks like a shell script started `ffmpeg`, yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ... but that `sh -c` is not the parent of the other process.

Comment: The argument list to `execl` is wrong anyway. Unless `ffmpeg` has a very unusual argument parser, `-video_size` wound be discarded as the _program name_ _if_ the arguments were properly split up as I suggested above. Right now, I would guess that the whole argument string `"-video_size 1024x768 -framerate 20 -f x11grab - i : 0.0"` will be discarded as the program name. Also, the argument string does not match what `ps` shows so - the processes does not come from the code shown.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should look into `std::thread`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks a lot! The -i parameter was a typo. When I executed the command it was correct hence is the ps output. I tried your suggestion and I don't see any process with program ffmpeg executing. I see 2 processes with the original program executing.

Comment: @kode_18  Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64976506/edit) the code in the question to what you actually have in your program. You could also add `sleep(1); system(("pstree -alp " + std::to_string(pid)).c_str());` before `return pid;` to make resonably sure that you only list the child process of the current run and its child processes.